# Importing MQ data into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, ibm-mq, flume

I want to import websphere MQ messages to  my hadoop VM using Flume.I have not used MQ before and  installed MQ version 8.0.0.4 on my windows machine and created JNDI binding . I have copied that JNDI binding file to the /etc/flume/conf location and created conf file for flume. Once i have started the Flume agent i am getting below error:-

```
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'JMSDEMO' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'XXX.XXX.XX.XX(1414)'
```

Below are the errors in the Log file of Websphere MQ:-

```
4/20/2016 22:00:18 - Process(14396.9) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(armaan) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(JMSDEMO)

AMQ9245: Unable to obtain account details for channel MCA user ID.

EXPLANATION:
WebSphere MQ was unable to obtain the account details for MCA user ID 'root'.
This user ID was the MCA user ID for channel 'SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN' on queue
manager 'JMSDEMO' and may have been defined in the channel definition, or
supplied either by a channel exit or by a client.
ACTION:
Ensure that the user ID is correct and that it is defined on the Windows local
system, the local domain or on a trusted domain. For a domain user ID, ensure
that all necessary domain controllers are available. 
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2140 -------------------------------------------------------
4/20/2016 22:00:18 - Process(6376.20) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(armaan) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(JMSDEMO)

AMQ7227: WebSphere MQ encountered the following network error: The trust
relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

EXPLANATION:
 MQ failed to successfully complete a network operation due to the specified
error. If the error is encountered on systems that are part of a Windows 2000
domain it can indicate incorrect DNS or WINS configuration.
ACTION:
Ensure that your network is functioning correctly. On the Windows platform
check DNS and/or WINS settings to ensure that domain controllers, used for
authentication or authorisation functions, are accessible. 
----- amqxsecn.c : 5125 -------------------------------------------------------
4/20/2016 22:00:18 - Process(6376.20) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(armaan) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(JMSDEMO)

AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'root' cannot be
obtained.

EXPLANATION:
The Object Authority Manager was unable to obtain a SID for the specified
entity. This could be because the local machine is not in the domain to locate
the entity, or because the entity does not exist.
ACTION:
Ensure that the entity is valid, and that all necessary domain controllers are
available. This might mean creating the entity on the local machine. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 2421 -------------------------------------------------------
4/20/2016 22:00:18 - Process(6376.20) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(armaan) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(JMSDEMO)

AMQ7227: WebSphere MQ encountered the following network error: The trust
relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

EXPLANATION:
 MQ failed to successfully complete a network operation due to the specified
error. If the error is encountered on systems that are part of a Windows 2000
domain it can indicate incorrect DNS or WINS configuration.
ACTION:
Ensure that your network is functioning correctly. On the Windows platform
check DNS and/or WINS settings to ensure that domain controllers, used for
authentication or authorisation functions, are accessible. 
----- amqxsecn.c : 5125 -------------------------------------------------------
4/20/2016 22:00:18 - Process(6376.20) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqzlaa0.exe)
                      Host(armaan) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(JMSDEMO)

AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'root' cannot be
obtained.

EXPLANATION:
The Object Authority Manager was unable to obtain a SID for the specified
entity. This could be because the local machine is not in the domain to locate
the entity, or because the entity does not exist.
ACTION:
Ensure that the entity is valid, and that all necessary domain controllers are
available. This might mean creating the entity on the local machine. 
----- amqzfubn.c : 2421 -------------------------------------------------------
4/20/2016 22:00:18 - Process(14396.9) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(armaan) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(JMSDEMO)

AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'root'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'root' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again. 
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 2321 -------------------------------------------------------
```

I have submitted the flume command from VM as root user.
I know i had done something wrong with MQ settings as i have noprevious experience with MQ . Please help .

Answer (score 1):

> I know i had done something wrong with MQ settings as i have
>   no previous experience with MQ.

How about doing some self-training and read the documentation.  There is a whole section in the [MQ Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q001010_.htm) about MQ & JMS.  Please read it [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q118320_.htm).  Or you could go to the largest conference in the world solely dedicated to IBM MQ (aka WebSphere MQ & MQSeries) - [MQ Technical Conference v2.0.1.6](http://www.mqtechconference.com/).

Just put the credentials as follows:

```
QueueConnection conn = cf.createQueueConnection(userID, password);
```